# Ajax PUT request successful but not updating on database

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am performing an AJAX PUT request which is coming back as successful but not updating on the database.

Have checked to make sure the variables going into the array are correct before being converted to JSON.

```
var recycle = {
    id:document.getElementById('id').value,
    year:document.getElementById('year').value,
    materialThousandTonnes:document.getElementById('material').value,
    packagingWasteArising:document.getElementById('packaging').value,
    totalRecoveredRecycled:document.getElementById('total').value,
    achievedRecoveryRecyclingRate:document.getElementById('achieved').value,
    euTargetRecoveryRecyclingRate:document.getElementById('target').value
};

$.ajax({
    url: '/recycle',
    method: 'PUT',
    data: JSON.stringify(recycle),
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("hi");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR + '\n' + textStatus + '\n' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

The alert "hi" appears everytime however it doesn't actually PUT the data into my database please help!

EDIT:

Here is server-side code for PUT request

```
 public function performPut($url, $parameters, $requestBody, $accept) 
    {
        global $dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbdatabase;

        $newRecycle = $this->extractRecycleFromJSON($requestBody);
        $connection = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbdatabase);
        if (!$connection->connect_error)
        {
            $sql = "update recycledb set year = ?, materialThousandTonnes = ?, packagingWasteArising = ?, totalRecoveredRecycled = ?, achievedRecoveryRecyclingRate = ?, euTargetRecoveryRecyclingRate = ? where id = ?";
            // We pull the fields of the book into local variables since 
            // the parameters to bind_param are passed by reference.
            $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $id = $newRecycle->getId();
            $year = $newRecycle->getYear();
            $materialThousandTonnes = $newRecycle->getMaterialThousandTonnes();
            $packagingWasteArising = $newRecycle->getPackagingWasteArising();
            $totalRecoveredRecycled = $newRecycle->getTotalRecoveredRecycled();
            $achievedRecoveryRecyclingRate = $newRecycle->getAchievedRecoveryRecyclingRate();
            $euTargetRecoveryRecyclingRate = $newRecycle->getEuTargetRecoveryRecyclingRate();
            $statement->bind_param('iisiiss', $id, $year, $materialThousandTonnes, $packagingWasteArising, $totalRecoveredRecycled, $achievedRecoveryRecyclingRate, $euTargetRecoveryRecyclingRate);
            $result = $statement->execute();
            if ($result == FALSE)
            {
                $errorMessage = $statement->error;
            }
            $statement->close();
            $connection->close();
            if ($result == TRUE)
            {
                // We need to return the status as 204 (no content) rather than 200 (OK) since
                // we are not returning any data
                $this->noContentResponse();
            }
            else
            {
                $this->errorResponse($errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the actual server working properly?

Comment: Yes, I am able to add data with ajax using 'POST'

Comment: the problem **may** be with the code on the server side - so ... you haven't supplied enough information to get any help

Comment: Is the server actually configured to support `PUT` requests? And if it does work with `POST` requests then why don't you just use `POST` requests?

Comment: If post is working and PUT is not, likely an issue with your back end. Open browser dev tools network tab...will see exactly what is being sent when you dig into the details of the actual request

Comment: Thank you for responses, I have updated my question with server-side code

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution to my issue after much a struggle

On this line:

```
$statement->bind_param('iisiiss', $id, $year, $materialThousandTonnes, $packagingWasteArising, $totalRecoveredRecycled, $achievedRecoveryRecyclingRate, $euTargetRecoveryRecyclingRate);
```

The id variable needed to be moved to the end of the statement...

Like this:

```
$statement->bind_param('iisiiss', $year, $materialThousandTonnes, $packagingWasteArising, $totalRecoveredRecycled, $achievedRecoveryRecyclingRate, $euTargetRecoveryRecyclingRate, $id);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$statement->bind_param('iisiiss', $year, $materialThousandTonnes, $packagingWasteArising, $totalRecoveredRecycled, $achievedRecoveryRecyclingRate, $euTargetRecoveryRecyclingRate, $id);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Most answers contain some non-code explanation of how it works and describe its merit for solving the problem.

Comment: The code you have provided was already posted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55961863/ajax-put-request-successful-but-not-updating-on-database/55962178#55962178) to this same question. Answers are expected to add information not already given elsewhere in the question or one of its answers. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22913408)